# How much influence does King's "The Dark Tower" have on Overwatch?

Tags: stephen-king, the-dark-tower, overwatch

[This reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/5eehkq/overwatch_and_the_dark_tower/) implies that some Overwatch characters may have been created under *The Dark Tower* influence. Namely, McCree and Reaper might be based on Roland and The Man in Black respectively.

I also find it interesting, that Orisa is both the character name and the name of the weapon in DT: Wolves of Kalla.

**Is there any confirmation of how all of this is related?**

Comment: Overwatch also shares the character name "Sombra" with the Dark Tower series' Sombra Corporation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it certainly seems to be the case. The only credible proof I can give is that there are unused data mined voice lines which refer to the Dark Tower series.

[Reaper voice](https://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Reaper/Quotes)

> The man in black followed...

[McCree voice](https://clyp.it/3kc2jxoc)

> And the gunslinger followed...